# Create regex from object keys

Tags: javascript, regex, underscore.js

How can I simplify the following better using Underscore? It feels like too much code for something very simple. It creates a regex from the object keys.

```
var obj = {
   'dog' : 1,
   'cat' : 1,
   'rat' : 1
};

var arr = [], regex;

_.each( obj, function( value, index ){
  arr.push( index );
});

regex = _.reduce( arr, function(){
  return new RegExp( arr.join('|'), 'i' );
});

// console.log( regex ) should output: 
/dog|cat|rat/i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and native [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) like this

```
console.log(new RegExp(Object.keys(obj).join("|"), "i"));
```

With `_`, it will be [`_.keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys)

```
console.log(new RegExp(_.keys(obj).join("|"), "i"));
```

The result would be

```
/dog|cat|rat/i
```

Comment: Awesome, I landed on the first one, but +1 for included the Underscore version.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly figured that you don't need to use underscore for this.

```
 var regex = new RegExp( Object.keys( obj ).join('|'), 'i' );
```